# How to create a COUNTIFS criteria that checks if a value in a cell matches any value in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check if the value of a column A matches any value in a column B.

What I am trying to do would match the functionality of doing as follows:
COUNTIFS(A:A, B1, A:A, B2, A:A, B3, ...) and so on until I have reached the end of B. However, I want to generalize this so that it will update if I add something to the column B. Please let me know if there's any way to do this.

Comment: Welcome! Why not simple `=ArrayFormula(COUNT(MATCH(A1:A,B1:B,0)))`?

Comment: @JohnSUN Why didn't you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @Tedinoz I am preparing a screenshot so that it is clear what is coming from and how it works. And that takes time...

Answer (score 1):

The formula `=ArrayFormula(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0))` will try to find each of the cells in column A in column B (For clarity, the result of this expression is shown in the figure in column D - this intermediate result is not needed for real calculation)

[image: Demo]

As you can see, if the cell is not found in column B, then the result of the calculation is "error **#N/A**". Otherwise, this is a number, the position of the cell value from column A in column B. We are not interested in a specific value, the type of result is important - a number or an error. The COUNT() function will return the number of numbers resulting from this expression and ignore errors. So the final formula that solves your problem is

`=ArrayFormula(COUNT(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0)))`

Comment: I like this formula; the only "problem" is that it is an infinite range, so it extends to the bottom of the spreadsheet. You can see the start of this in rows 23,24,25.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in Cell D1:

`=query({UNIQUE(A2:A),ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(B2:B,UNIQUE(A2:A)))} ,"select * where Col2<>0  label Col1 'Source', Col2 'Count'")`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]